# html5lib. How to get valid html without adding html, head and body tags?

Tags: python, dom, html-parsing, html5lib

I'm validating custom HTML from users with **html5lib**.  The problem is the html5lib adds `html`, `head` and `body` tags, which I don't need.

```
parser = html5lib.HTMLParser(tree=treebuilders.getTreeBuilder("simpleTree"))
f = open('/home/user/ex.html')
doc = parser.parse(f)
doc.toxml()
'<html><head/><body><div>\n  <a href="http://speedhunters.com">speedhunters.com\n</a></div><a href="http://speedhunters.com">\n</a></body></html>'
```

This is validated, can be sanitized, but how can I remove or prevent adding these tags to the tree?
I mean exclude `replace` using.

Comment: So, I want to have a cat, but I don't need it to have legs...

Comment: This is the part of the page, which user can customize, so I need just a good cat's tail.

Comment: Fair enough, that's a reasonable use case. Just checking you were not trying to produce some horribly mangled output.

Comment: @Lattyware, what do you think about how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, html5lib has horrible documentation.

Looking through the source, and working on a quick test case, this appears to work:

```
import html5lib
from html5lib import treebuilders
parser = html5lib.HTMLParser(tree=treebuilders.getTreeBuilder("simpleTree"))
with open('test.html') as test:
    doc = parser.parse(test)
    for child in doc:
        if child.parent.name == "body":
            return child.toxml()
```

It's a bit hackish, but less so than a `replace()`.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that we can use the `hidden` property of `Tag`s in order to prevent the tag itself from being 'exported' when casting a tag/soup to string/unicode:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = u"<div><footer><h3>foot</h3></footer></div><div>foo</div>"
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib")
>>> print soup.body.prettify()
<body>
 <div>
  <footer>
   <h3>
    foot
   </h3>
  </footer>
 </div>
 <div>
  foo
 </div>
</body>
```

Essentially, the questioner's goal is to get the entire content of the `body` tag without the `<body>` wrapper itself. This works:

```
>>> soup.body.hidden=True
>>> print soup.body.prettify()
 <div>
  <footer>
   <h3>
    foot
   </h3>
  </footer>
 </div>
 <div>
  foo
 </div>
```

I found this by going through the BeautifulSoup source. After calling `soup = BeautifulSoup(html)`, the root tag has the internal name '[document]'. By default, only the root tag has `hidden==True`. This prevents its name from ending up in any HTML output.

Answer (score 1):

[lxml](http://lxml.de/) may be a better choice if you're dealing with "uncommon" html.